# Access name of .rmd file and use in R

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am knitting a markdown file called `MyFile.rmd`.
How can I access the string `MyFile` during the knitting and use it for:

- use in the title section of the YAML header?
- use in subsequent R chunk?

  ````
  ---
  title: "`r rmarkdown::metadata$title`"
  author: "My Name"
  date: "10. Mai 2015"
  output: beamer_presentation
  ---

  ## Slide 1

  ```{r}

  rmarkdown::metadata$title

  ```
  ````

leads to...

[image]

... which is incorrect as the file I am knitting is named differently.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.8    htmltools_0.2.6 rmarkdown_0.5.1 tools_3.1.2     yaml_2.1.13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summarize Yihui's answer:

````
    ---
    title: "`r knitr::current_input()`"
    author: "My Name"
    date: "10. Mai 2015"
    output: beamer_presentation
    ---

    ## Slide 1

    ```{r}

    knitr::current_input()

    ```
````

which knitted does the job.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

`rmarkdown::metadata` gives you the list of the meta data of the R Markdown, e.g. `rmarkdown::metadata$title` will be the title of your document. An example:

````
---
title: "Beamer Presentation Title"
author: "My Name"
date: "10\. Mai 2015"
output: beamer_presentation
---

## Slide 1

Print the title in a code chunk.

```{r}
rmarkdown::metadata$title
```

## Slide 2

The title of the document is `r rmarkdown::metadata$title`.
````

To obtain the filename of the input document, use `knitr::current_input()`.

Comment: Thx Yihui, for R chunk it works. For the YAML title section I need further help. Using title: "`r rmarkdown::metadata$title " does not work.

Comment: @user2030503 I cannot reproduce it. Please edit your post, and elaborate what "does not work" means (along with `sessionInfo()`).

Comment: Dear Yihui, the question is modified.

Comment: @user2030503 You should not write inline R code inside R code chunks. It seems you need to learn the basics about knitr first. Here are some minimal examples: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/minimal/

Comment: Dear Yihui, sorry but even after reading more about knitr I do not come up with a solution.

Comment: @user2030503 Please see the example in my answer.

Comment: This answer solves 50% of the question. Still unsolved is the first part about how to automatically use the filename in the header of the YAML section

Comment: You can use `knitr::current_input()`.

Comment: Thx Yihui for your kind help. In order to document the final solution I made a separate answer, but the credit goes to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `yaml` library, like so:

```
library(yaml)

# Read in the lines of your file
lines <- readLines("MyFile.rmd")
# Find the header portion contained between the --- lines. 
header_line_nums <- which(lines == "---") + c(1, -1)
# Create a string of just that header portion
header <- paste(lines[seq(header_line_nums[1], 
                          header_line_nums[2])], 
                collapse = "\n")
# parse it as yaml, which returns a list of property values
yaml.load(header)
```

If you save the list returned by `yaml.load`, you can use it in various chunks as needed. To get the title, you can do this:

```
properties <- yaml.load(header)
properties$title
```

Comment: Ah! I found it. The `rmarkdown` package develops a function `yaml_front_matter` to do the lines you have written here.