# How to get section name in an .rmd file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is it possible to capture the name of a section as a variable?

I have an .rmd document where each section follows the same format e.g.,

```
# The Beginning


### What we know about The Beginning


### What we need to learn about The Beginning
```

...

and I'd like to write something more generalized like

```
# The Beginning


### What we know about `r section_name`


### What we need to learn about `r section_name`
```

Is there a way to capture the current section name?

Comment: Good question, but I think your only way is going to be using `\`r somevar\`` as you've hinted at here. That is, before the `#` heading (and each subsequent heading), assign `hdg1 <- "The Beginning"`. I'll be really curious to see if there is a more convenient way to do this!

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case, but then I learned about `rmarkdown::metadata` while I was researching the question, so I thought I'd try my luck

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153194/access-name-of-rmd-file-and-use-in-r) could help

Answer (score 1):

If you name a chunk 'The Beginning' you can refer to it throughout the Rmd using `knitr::all_labels()`, e.g.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Jared_Mamrot"
date: "22/12/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

# The Beginning
```{r The Beginning}
summary(cars)
```

### What we know about `r knitr::all_labels()[2]`
```{r 3rd_chunk}
# Refer to the 'label' inside the chunk
knitr::all_labels()[2]
```

### What we need to learn about `r knitr::all_labels()[2]`
```{r 4th_chunk}
cars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle(label = knitr::all_labels()[2]) +
  theme_bw()
```
````

When I knit the Rmd, `knitr::all_labels()[2]` is replaced with "The Beginning"

[image: example_knitted.png]

**EDIT:**
After re-reading your question I realise that this is not a complete answer. Perhaps you could somehow adapt [this function for printing a Table of Contents](https://gist.github.com/gadenbuie/c83e078bf8c81b035e32c3fc0cf04ee8) to grab the section header and use it in the knitted doc.